# 3' or 5' DNA capping protein

Tags: dna, ligation

Does anyone know of a protein/molecule that can be attached to one end of the DNAs temporarily ? eg. i would like to only to allow one strand of DNA be ligated to another DNA molecule to either it's 3' or 5' but not both. thanks

Comment: Could you explain what you're hoping to accomplish a bit more? Why wouldn't it be possible just to put RE sites at one end of your DNA and the correct end of the piece to be ligated, digest with the RE and then ligate the digest?

Comment: Alternatively, you could do fusion PCR/Polymerase Cycling Assembly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymerase_cycling_assembly . PCR up your fragments with additions to the primers complementary to the other piece you want to connect to, then combine the two pieces (now with short complementary regions) and do another PCR to make the full product.

Comment: Thanks A. Kennard for giving me the answer. you are right.